# Group count results by month

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to obtain types of attendances per year/month in order to populate a bar chart.
These are my two tables ( I know the english is a bit off ):

```
**presences**
ID | Id_student | Id_class | Presence
3        2           27         1
4        4           28         2
...     ...         ...        ...

**class**
ID | Id_schedule | Date_class | State
27        6        2017-12-11     1
28        7        2018-01-13     1
...      ...          ...        ...
```

This is my current queries, which returns ALL results instead of the intended result, which is just the current year:

```
   SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(Date_class, '%Y') as 'year', DATE_FORMAT(Date_class, '%M') as 'month',
        (SELECT COUNT(distinct ID) FROM presences WHERE Presence = 0) as Faltas,
        (SELECT COUNT(distinct ID) FROM presences WHERE Presence = 1) as Pre,
        (SELECT COUNT(distinct ID) FROM presences WHERE Presence = 2) as Temp,
        (SELECT COUNT(distinct ID) FROM presences WHERE Presence = 3) as Canc,
        (SELECT COUNT(distinct ID) FROM presences WHERE Presence = 4) as FaltasTemp
    FROM class, presences
    WHERE YEAR(Date_class) = YEAR(CURDATE())
    AND
    presences.Id_class = class.ID
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(Date_class, '%Y%m')
```

This is the result, which is also displaying occurrences from last year:

```
year  month  Faltas Pre Temp Canc FaltasTemp
2018 January   2     6   5    0       1
```

Could anyone help me identify what is missing?

Comment: You do not have a where clause concerning the date in the queries which give you the counts, so why would you expect them to return only counts over the current year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a much simpler query:

```
   SELECT YEAR(c.Date_class) as year, MONTH(c.Date_class) as month,
          SUM(p.Presence = 0) as Faltas,
          SUM(p.Presence = 1) as Pre,
          SUM(p.Presence = 2) as Temp,
          SUM(p.Presence = 3) as Canc,
          SUM(p.Presence = 4) as FaltasTemp
    FROM class c JOIN
         presences p
         ON p.Id_class = c.ID
    WHERE YEAR(c.Date_class) = YEAR(CURDATE())
    GROUP BY YEAR(c.Date_class), MONTH(c.Date_class);
```

Notes:

- Use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax. *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- The tables have aliases, which make the queries easier to write and to read.
- The columns are all qualified (with the table name) so you know where they come from.
- You don't need a separate subquery for each column.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but most importantly, your notes which will hopefully help me write better queries.